# Why android service is not working in release build?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, background-process

In my application, an android service is used to connect to a printer. The service is not working in Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime in release build. Debug build is working very fine in the same phone. Also both the builds are working fine in other phones i tested. Application is crashing and Application not responding dialog is coming in Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime. Can any one please help me with this?

```
public class DrawerService1 extends Service {
    // Service?workThread???mHandler
    public static WorkThread1 workThread = null;
    private static Handler mHandler = null;
    private static List<Handler> targetsHandler = new ArrayList<Handler>(5);

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mHandler = new MHandler(this);
        workThread = new WorkThread1(mHandler);
        workThread.start();
        Log.v("DrawerService", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("DrawerService", "onStartCommand");
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = Global1.MSG_ALLTHREAD_READY;
        notifyHandlers(msg);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        workThread.disconnectNet();
        workThread.quit();
        workThread = null;
        Log.v("DrawerService", "onDestroy");
    }

    static class MHandler extends Handler {

        WeakReference<DrawerService1> mService;

        MHandler(DrawerService1 service) {
            mService = new WeakReference<DrawerService1>(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            notifyHandlers(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param handler
     */
    public static void addHandler(Handler handler) {
        if (!targetsHandler.contains(handler)) {
            targetsHandler.add(handler);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param handler
     */
    public static void delHandler(Handler handler) {
        if (targetsHandler.contains(handler)) {
            targetsHandler.remove(handler);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param msg
     */
    public static void notifyHandlers(Message msg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < targetsHandler.size(); i++) {
            Message message = Message.obtain(msg);
            targetsHandler.get(i).sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

see the log here:

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in "package name"

                                              PID: 26266

                                              Reason: executing service packagename/.DrawerService1

                                              Load: 7.57 / 6.16 / 6.95

                                              CPU usage from 0ms to 11426ms later:

                                                198% 26266/packagename: 197% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 800 minor 16 major

                                                70% 1350/system_server: 20% user + 50% kernel / faults: 8360 minor 90 major

                                                43% 2460/android.process.acore: 35% user + 7.5% kernel / faults: 4571 minor 6 major

                                                17% 2284/com.android.phone: 6.4% user + 11% kernel / faults: 5197 minor 42 major

                                                10% 1703/com.android.systemui: 3.7% user + 6.7% kernel / faults: 3389 minor 4 major

                                                10% 5332/com.miui.home: 6.5% user + 3.8% kernel / faults: 3516 minor 10 major

                                                0% 620/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8630 minor 36 major

                                                4.2% 2150/com.miui.whetstone: 1.8% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 2201 minor 10 major

                                                3.8% 427/surfaceflinger: 1.6% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 36 minor 1 major

                                                3.3% 2060/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 1.7% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 1764 minor 3 major

                                                3% 22701/com.whatsapp: 1.4% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 1014 minor

                                                0% 2182/com.xiaomi.finddevice: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3214 minor 4 major

                                                0% 621/debuggerd64: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3619 minor 15 major

                                                1.6% 1817/com.xiaomi.xmsf: 1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 2158 minor 6 major

                                                1.5% 2109/com.quicinc.cne.CNEService: 1.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 2159 minor 9 major

                                                1.2% 2273/com.qualcomm.qti.tetherservice: 0.6% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1813 minor 2 major

                                                0% 1837/com.miui.core: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2687 minor 3 major

                                                1.1% 2131/com.qti.dpmserviceapp: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 2861 minor 3 major

                                                1% 2068/com.google.android.gms: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 700 minor 2 major

                                                0.1% 2159/com.fingerprints.serviceext: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1753 minor 2 major

                                                1% 25811/kworker/u16:5: 0% user + 1% kernel

                                                0.8% 449/mm-pp-dpps: 0.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 12 minor

                                                0.8% 25472/kworker/u16:2: 0% user + 0.8% kernel

                                                0.7% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.7% kernel

                                                0.7% 243/irq/402-ft5x06_: 0% user + 0.7% kernel

                                                0.7% 357/logd: 0.3% user + 0.4% kernel

                                                0.7% 26453/com.ideashower.readitlater.pro: 0.6% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1818 minor 1 major

                                                0% 2121/com.qualcomm.qti.notificationservice: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2159 minor 1 major

                                                0% 2219/com.qualcomm.qti.carrierconfigure: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1763 minor 3 major

                                                0% 2244/com.quicinc.wbcserviceapp: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1613 minor 3 major

                                                0.6% 7625/kworker/u16:4: 0% user + 0.6% kernel

                                                0.6% 24161/adbd: 0.2% user + 0.4% kernel

                                                0.6% 24966/com.mfashiongallery.emag: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 1965 minor 321 major

                                                0.6% 323/mmc-cmdqd/0: 0% user + 0.6% kernel

                                                0.6% 426/servicemanager: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel

                                                0.6% 477/sensors.qcom: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 2 minor

                                                0% 2203/com.qualcomm.qti.loadcarrier: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1416 minor 1 major

                                                0.5% 8/rcu_sched: 0% user + 0.5% kernel

                                                0.5% 1974/com.jio.join: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2 minor

                                                0.3% 24/ksoftirqd/4: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

                                                0.3% 28/ksoftirqd/5: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

                                                0.3% 32/ksoftirqd/6: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

                                                0.3% 36/ksoftirqd/7: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

                                                0.3% 23066/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel

                                                0.2% 782/kworker/7:1H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel

                                                0.2% 26137/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel

                                                0.1% 295/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.1% kernel

                                                0.1% 613/jbd2/dm-1-8: 0% user + 0.1% kernel

                                                0.1% 2971/mcd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor 1 major

                                                0.1% 3014/perfd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 11 minor

                                                0% 27/migration/5: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 619/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 71 minor

                                                0% 634/cnss_diag: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 635/thermal-engine: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 651/loc_launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 783/msm_irqbalance: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 2967/VosMCThread: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 2969/VosRXThread: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 2973/wlan_logging_th: 0% user + 0% kernel

                                                0% 4106/com.miui.powerkeeper:service: 0% user + 0% kernel
```

02-27 14:34:26.178 1350-26517/? E/ActivityManager: Error reading /data/anr/traces.txt

```
                                               java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/anr/traces.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)

                                                   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)

                                                   at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:236)

                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$18.run(ActivityManagerService.java:12683)

                                                Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

                                                  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)

                                                   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)

                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)

                                                   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 

                                                   at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:236) 

                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$18.run(ActivityManagerService.java:12683)
```

Comment: Not without a stacktrace

Comment: in release build stack trace is not available

Comment: Check the google play crash reporter (it's integrated by default). Or find a 3rd party tool (i.e. ACRA, crashlytics, etc). You still need to add the stacktrace

Comment: added the logs got from the logcat. in crashlytics i am not getting any crash report after the crash